# ol li inside scrollbar differ between Chrome & Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

### Open at Chrome Browser: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/vKmRby)**

If `li` inside has `div` scroll bar the `ol li` number are not working.

### Open at Firefox Browser: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/wWdmOy)**

But,the same code `ol li` number has working on FF Browser.

#### I expected result is What is show on firefox. that is `ol li` has with number

What is that issue? i tried but not get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link it will help you.
http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/dXWZbp

```
ol {
    width:150px
}
ol li {
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-left:0px;
    display: list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
div {
    width:100px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hide in chrome because you used `overflow-x:scroll`

Please check jsfiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/awdmb6s1/

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:150px
}
li{
  padding-left:30px;
  position:relative;
  list-style:none

}
li:before {
   counter-increment: section;
    content: " "counter(section) ". ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
div{
  width:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this property in css `display:inline-block;` , `vertical-align: top;` in `div` tag & remove padding to `li` tag

```css
ol{
  width:150px;
}
ol li{
  padding-left:20px;/*remove this property*/
  margin-left:20px;
  
    
}
div{
  width:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
      display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
   
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><div>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting  </div> </li>
  <li><div>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting  </div> </li>
  <li><div>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting  </div> </li>
  
  
  </ol>
```